# Why Bootstrap classes don't work in some places?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to add h1 class to header text inside the span also align it horizontally center but bootstrap classes text-center and h1 is not working. later i found fs-1 and mx-auto works. What is this caused by? Is h1 element only usable inside the p tag?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>


    <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-light mt-3 rounded border border-3 border-dark " style="background-color: black;">
                <div class="container-fluid text-center ">
                <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1 text-center" style="color: white; cursive;">Header</span>
                </div>
            </nav>
     </div>

   


    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `navbar-brand` from your `span`, as that is overriding the `H1`'s font size. Your `span` also needs a class of `w-100` as it is in a flex box and will automatically take the minimal amount of size possible. Or instead of adding `w-100` to your `span` you can add the class `justify-content-center` to your container.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>


    <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-light mt-3 rounded border border-3 border-dark " style="background-color: black;">
                <div class="container-fluid text-center">
                <span class="mb-0 h1 w-100" style="color: white; cursive;">Header</span>
                </div>
            </nav>
     </div>

   


    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```